# Razor (cshtml) equivalent of using cURL (php) to call rest api

Tags: php, web-services, razor, curl, umbraco

I've successfully made a call to the rest api using curl like this:

```
 $curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $_POST["logInEmail"] . ":" . $_POST["logInPassword"]);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://<theURL>/api/session");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$result = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);

echo $result; //for testing, otherwise it would be inside a function and use return...
```

However, my work project is not in php, so I can't use this. I tried with AJAX but I get "Cross-Origin Request Blocked", so I have to look into doing this in Razor (cshtml).

I'd like to know if it is even possible to write this in cshtml.

UPDATE:
I got it to work eventually so I will post the code in case someone needs it in the future.

```
string _auth = string.Format("{0}:{1}", "username","password");
string _enc = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_auth));

var url = "http://api url";

var client = new WebClient();

client.Headers.Add("contentType", "application/json");
client.Headers.Add("Authorization", "BASIC " + _enc);

var content = client.UploadString(url, "");
var search = Json.Decode(content);
```

Then just I use the search variable to use the data from the response (in this case it returns user's details and auth token and I set up a local session).

Also if someone can explain why this should not be done in a razor script, that will be great (as per Morten OC's comment).

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Do you really want an AJAX call in the browser or just to pull some data from a REST API in your server application?

Comment: The REST API will be used for Creating users, Loging in users and some other things. I need to call the API with POST and send user details when user signs up and call the API with POST & basic auth header to log in, if login is successful the api returns user's details as json.

Comment: Still sounds like you need to be calling the API from the server and not the browser.

Comment: As far as I know, a razor script runs on the server, not on the client/browser. So I want to contact the API using a razor script inside something like: bool isPost = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Form["submit-button"]);
if(IsPost) {
// contact the api and do stuff with the response
}

Comment: You should NOT have this kind of logic in a razor file.. Create a controller, or a webservice that contacts your login API. If you create a controller, then use a normal <form> element in razor that makes a post to this controller. If you create a webservice, you can make an ajax call (with js) to this local webservice without CORS.

Comment: @MortenOC I guess MrVentzi is not using MVC or Webform, but he is using Webpages(Razor). Go to VS2013->New->Websites->Razor3. I am trying the same thing and stumped on this post.